# Enable Firefox DNS over HTTPS breaks every site

Tags: networking, firefox, dns

I have been trying to play around with the DNS over HTTPS feature that has rolled out to firefox browsers. I have tried both Firefox 63, and the Nightly 65 release.

I set network.trr.mode = 3, and network.trr.uri to the default https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query, and to https://dns.google.com/experimental

If I understand correctly, the trr mode of 3 should force firefox to use dns over https. When I do this, literally no sites will load (google.com, cnn.com, stackoverflow.com).

What am I missing to enable the feature? If I set the mode to 2, it works, because I believe it defaults back to regular DNS lookups.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cloudflare DNS, set *network.trr.bootstrapAddress* with 1.1.1.1, or *network.trr.uri* with https://1.1.1.1/dns-query